# How to find related table/view name to use for from statement by using a value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table X in SQL Server which includes a column called `Type varchar(10)` with 15 potential values: `AAA, BBB1, BBB2, CCC, ...`, and another column called `IfExists bit`.

In the same DB, I have 15 different views, a view for each `Type`, including `X_ID` as well. Examples of view names:

```
View_ReportingAAA
View_ReportingBBB1
View_ReportingBBB2
View_ReportingCCC
....
```

Usually what I do is to see the `Type` of the record by using its `X_ID` provided to me in `Table X` and use a select query to the related view to get some data.

What I need to do is now to create a trigger for `Table X` to set 1 for the value of `IfExists` field if there is a record in the related view for the record id `X_ID`.

**My question is:** What is the best way to find and use the related view name for this purpose by using a value of a field in the main table?

I am using the code below for this, but I am not sure if it is the most efficient way to handle this. Any help or advice would be appreciated.

```
declare @ifExists int = 0;
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 'set @ifExists = (Select count(*) from View_Reporting';

declare @tablename nvarchar(max) = (Select Type from X where X_ID = @X_ID)

set @sql = @sql + @tablename + ' where V_xid = @X_ID)';
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql

if (@ifExists > 0)
begin
   update X set IfExists = 1 where X_ID = @X_ID
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could be easier:

```
declare @ifExists bit
select @ifExists=count(*) from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
    where TABLE_NAME='View_Reporting'+(select [Type] from X where X_ID=@X_ID)
update X set IfExists=@IfExists where X_ID=@X_ID and IfExists<>@IfExists
```